# NR4 box conversion to a 1099DIV

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks, canada

I have box 26 on a NR4, and in box 28 the code "Q".  Where do I put these on a 1099DIV?

I am using Turbo Tax, and was told that I need to use a 1099DIV, converting the information on the NR4 to a 1099DIV. I am doing my US 1040. I know that Box 16 (NR4) correlates to box 1B on the 1099, and that box 17 (NR4) correlates to box 6 on the 1099.  My problem is there is a small money number in box 26 (NR4), and the code "Q" in box 28, and I don't know what to do with those on the 1099.

I worked for a company in the US that is a privately held Canadian company, hence the NR4.  I bought stock in the company, but when I quit working I was required to sell the stock back to the company.  It was disbursed as gross income by Canada, and I paid Non-resident taxes on the money.  The income code is 09.  I don't want to do it wrong.  Thank you for asking for more details.

Comment: We need more information.  Are you working on a Canadian tax form, or a U.S. tax form?  Why are you filling out a 1099-DIV?  Why did you receive an NR4?

Comment: A us tax form.  I received the NR4 because I worked for a Canadian company that has US offices; I had stock in the company; when I quit working for the company, I had to sell the stock back to them as it is a privately held company.  So, I have the NR4, which shows the codes 09 and "Q".  It shows total income disbursed, and the taxes paid to Canada, which I have figured out where they go on the US 1099-DIV.  But in Box 26 there is another small amount, and Box 28 has the code "Q".  I don't know where to input those on the 1099.

Comment: A Form 1099-DIV is something you receive from the entity that pays the dividend. Why do you think you need to put onto a 1099-DIV at all? It seems like you received rather than paid.

Comment: Are you perhaps using software to do your taxes, and you think that you need to enter this NR4 form into the software as if it was a 1099-DIV?

Comment: I received money from selling the stock back, but also paid taxes on it to Canada.  I am using Turbo Tax.  And yes, I was told to enter it as if it were a 1099DIV form, not a NR4.

Comment: Ben Miller - I am using Turbo Tax Deluxe, and other info on this site said to enter it as a 1099DIV.

Comment: Brick - I received a distribution AND paid canadian taxes as a non-resident.  There is no place I can find in the US tax forms that applies to a NR4.  Any ideas?